# Facebook sponsored timeline posts..is it allowed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was wondering whether it's allowed or not to have a FB app, which would eventually post into user's timeline(on behalf of the user) some user related stuff(which doesn't matter at this point) and also a logo(image) of one of the app's sponsors??
Would this app still be in compliance with FB's policy?

I've read the FB's policy already, but i'm not sure if it's very clear to me, whether it's allowed or not.

thx a lot.

Comment: The message has to be a 100% user generated, i.e. typed in by the user, and your app is not allowed to append anything to it. You can however let your users share a link to your app (and let them add their own message to that post). Explicit user consent is essential though. You are not allowed to get posting permission from the user once and then post whenever you feel like it; the user should rather trigger each single post actively.

Comment: You're right. I forgot to mention that "one post" would come right after a specific action made by the user, which in this case is totally aware of it being posted into his timeline. So, considering the user is aware of it and a post would happen right after an action made by himself, do you think this app would still be in compliance w/ FB's policy?

Comment: I guess then it's still not user generated, or?

Comment: Again: If you post a message, then it has to be a 100% user generated. Everything else will not be compliant with platform policies. However, depending on what kind of information you actually want to publish (still not clear on that), you might want to look into Open Graph Stories.

Comment: Great!! seems like Open Graph Stories is closer to what i'm looking for! I guess the question now is: How come I never thought of it!? :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this adheres to the Facebook platform policies:

- https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control

Specially **points 2.1 - 2.3 and 5.4** might be interesting:

> 2.1. Obtain consent from people before publishing content on their
>       behalf.
>
> 2.2. Use publishing permissions to help people share on Facebook, not to
>       send people messages from your app.
>
> 2.3. Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message
>       parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the
>       person can edit or remove the content before sharing.
>
> 5.4 Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.

Comment: I guess I was not clear. A post would come right after a user action and he is totally aware of it. So there's the user's consent. Also the post's content is based off the user action previous to the post.